# import existing conda environment from network location

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

*Brief description of the situation:*

We have some image analysis workstations running Windows which I can book on an hourly basis. When I log in, my user account is loaded from the domain and my network drives are automatically mounted.

I'm now looking for a way to install python on these workstations in a manageable way, meaning:

- each user would want to use their own set of packages and dependencies
- users should have access to their packages and dependencies regardless of which specific workstation they booked.
- for safety/maintainability, users are not allowed to install anything on the systems
- users packages cannot be maintained centrally

*After a bit of googling, I came up with the following workflow:*

Install a vanilla anaconda on each of the workstations for all users. This will be updated/maintained as the need arises. In order to give the users flexibility, they would install one/several conda environment(s) on their network drives.

*I started testing:*

Everything seems to work fine on the PC I used to create the environment using

```
conda create -p Z:\path\to\env\my-env python=3.7 anaconda
conda activate Z:\path\to\env\my-env
pip install somepackages
conda install somemorepackages
```

I can run code from ipython, jupyter notebook ...

On a different PC however, I run into issues:

I added the network path using `conda config --add envs_dirs Z:\path\to\env`. I am able to activate the environment using `conda activate Z:\path\to\env\my-env`. I can also `import` packages that are installed in the environment, but not in the base anaconda (I tested with `napari`).
However, with some other packages (`dask_image.imread`) I get an error message:

WARNING: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

*My question is now two-fold:*

- am I choosing the most feasible way? If not, what should be done differently?
- if it's the best way, how do I fix the error message? I am guessing that the created environment is missing some dependency or path because I'm executing on two systems. When I google for solutions, it's mostly users trying to install into folders with non-unicode characters, so not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows ...
the PCs were setup by IT such that the assignment of the drive letters is somewhat arbitrary.

So activating the environments works, but then the absolute paths written within the environment point to a non-existing location (now also the error message `could not find or load ... in ""` makes much more sense - python is trying to load a dependency from a path which does not exist).

Workaround (for now): I'm making sure that the drive letters are consistent, then everything works.

I'm going to test if it's possible to install environments with relative paths, because this should solve the issue all together.